# How do I utilize TunnelBroker's free /48 block of IPv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel

From what I understand, TunnelBroker is a service that acts as your ISP and allows you a public IPv6 address pointing directly to your machine even if it is behind a NAT.

From what I **don't** understand, TunnelBroker claims to give you a free /48 block of IPv6 addresses. That's >65k addresses. How do I use them? The only documentation I found regarding TunnelBroker was setting up a regular tunnel with one IPv6 using `sit0`. Say I had 65,000 computers, and I wanted each computer to be allocated an IPv6, would it be possible with the block of IPs I was given? Where do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Even though none of the actual reasons explained in that post apply here in the first place? It doesn't look like a "policy" question, and it doesn't look like a company-specific question. It looks like a networking question that happens to mention a company. (We've had so many of those that it's practically a duplicate.)

Comment: @grawity - Ask Different has a better FAQ on this type of question - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y -  but why should we be first-line support for any company's structure? The question shows little research.

Comment: No, by your logic, I think we could close literally all macOS-related questions on SU as "this is not Apple customer support". My point is, this question would remain exactly the same even if you removed all mentions of any company or product, which is not comparable to e.g. AppleID-related questions where the company is inseparable.

Comment: I'm hoping more for an answer relating to how networking with IPv6 works, especially with blocks of addresses, and less related to the service offering this address space. I also believe this answer will fill in the blank for information that is not widely available or easily accessible with IPv6.

Comment: The real problem with this question is that this information _is_ widely available; at its core it's one of the simplest routing exercises, and there are plenty of articles about both the generic parts (routing a subnet) and the IPv6-specific parts (Router Advertisements)... Some of the articles are even specifically about HE, but contrary to the above claims, it's a _very_ generic thing; 6to4 works the same way, native IPv6 works nearly the same way, SIXXS works kinda the same way. [Here's one example.](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Hurricane_Electric_Tunnel_Broker_Example_for_Home)

Comment: Yeah, maybe this question deserves to be closed for lack of research, or possibly as a duplicate.   But I agree with @grawity.   I believe that this close reason — “does not appear to be about computer software or computer hardware …” / “Basic Customer Support” — is inappropriate.   By that logic, all questions about Microsoft Word, Excel, Command Prompt, PowerShell, etc., should be closed because the OP should just go and ask Microsoft (hah!), and all questions about GNU software should be closed because the OP should just go and ask the Free Software Foundation.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  [The answer to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1672723#255746) [the linked Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1672723 "Why can’t I ask customer service-related questions?") says that people shouldn’t ask questions on [SE] that are company policy or company-proprietary, “because we don’t know the answer.”  But the rest of the argument is that this question is off-topic because the answer is ***too** easily accessible* (as [grawity demonstrated](https://superuser.com/q/1410541/150988#1410569)). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … People often try to close questions by saying, basically, ‘‘RTFM’’, and the frequently-made counter argument is: “So what if the answer is somewhere else?  Why shouldn’t it be here, also?  Super User’s purpose is to build a knowledge base that will be useful to others in the future.  Google has to index something, so it might as well be SE, right?”  I’m voting to reopen this, if only so it can be closed for an appropriate reason.

Answer (score 6):

> From what I understand, TunnelBroker is a service that acts as your ISP and allows you a public IPv6 address pointing directly to your machine even if it is behind a NAT.

Well, yes. You can also call it a kind of a VPN, basically. However, the bit about "...even if it is behind a NAT" is somewhat misleading:

1. These IPv6 tunnels are not meant as a NAT bypass method for individual devices; they're meant to deliver IPv6 connectivity to your *router*, and from there to the whole LAN at once. (Which indeed works just as if it were provided by your real ISP.)
2. Once the entire LAN has IPv6 connectivity, there's no "...even if" in that statement anymore. The devices simply *aren't* behind a NAT in the IPv6 network.

   (NAT is specific to each network protocol, so even though your LAN devices are still behind a NAT in the IPv4 network, they're simultaneously not behind a NAT in IPv6.)

> TunnelBroker claims to give you a free /48 block of IPv6 addresses. That's >65k addresses

That's >65k subnets, each having a practically-infinite amount of addresses, due to the full IPv6 address length being 128 bits and the "standard" subnet size being /64.

> How do I use them?

You use a router for that. (As mentioned above, either configure the tunnel on a router, or turn the tunnel endpoint *into* a router if it's capable of it.)

- The tunnel configuration is the same as before: the device still has its own address (the "Client IPv6 address" from tunnel info), it just *additionally* receives traffic meant for the extra "routed /48" network.

  You don't need to change the tunnel on your side for this to happen; it's enabled by the ISP (Hurricane) updating the routing table on their endpoint.

  (You can even completely ignore the fact that it's a tunnel; everything works the same way as if you were receiving the IP connectivity over a plain Ethernet cable. The only difference from, say, native ISP-provided IPv6 is that you don't need to use DHCPv6-PD to begin receiving the traffic.)
- Once the router begins receiving traffic meant for the new network, it gets to decide where to send it further. Usually you start by subdividing the /48 into standard /64-sized subnets, and just assigning one of them to the LAN interface or to some VLAN. For example, if you had `2001:db8:123::/48`, start with assigning `2001:db8:123:1::1/64` on your LAN interface.

  (This part is nearly identical to configuring networks in IPv4.)
- Finally, set up an address auto-configuration service for your LAN. Instead of DHCP, in IPv6 the primary autoconfiguration mechanism is SLAAC, i.e. "Router Advertisements".
- Besides TunnelBroker (also known as HE.net from the company), chances are that you'll find many tutorials about configuring a router for "6to4" or other services. They all work the same as far as LAN usage is concerned. Here are configuration examples for [Mikrotik RouterOS](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Hurricane_Electric_Tunnel_Broker_Example_for_Home), for [Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/884215/using-windows-as-ipv6-router-for-the-network), for [Gentoo Linux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/IPv6_router_guide), for [generic Linux](http://ktaraghi.blogspot.com/2014/07/linux-as-ipv6-router.html).

Comment: SixXS shut down years ago.