# How can I give IPv6 to WSL2?

Tags: ipv6

*Originally posted on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67470/how-can-i-give-ipv6-to-wsl2)*

**EDIT**: *This network configuration is no longer reflecting the network I'm connected to now. I'm switching ISPs (not of my own volition, the old IPv4-only ISP is officially no longer independent) and the new ISP has IPv6 and prefix delegation. I'm waiting for the switch in order to see if Hyper-V supports DHCP-PD (I know from someone already on this ISP that VMware does support it). I'll leave this post here for reference.*

I intend to give IPv6 connectivity to WSL2 running on my system. Here is a bit of the existing configuration:

- IPv6 router (TunnelBroker client):

  - Raspberry Pi 3 B+, Raspbian Buster.
  - Interface he-ipv6 has IP 2001:470:AAAA:BBBB::2/64 and is directly on Tunnel Broker.
  - Interface br0 (bridge between Eth and Wi-Fi, preexisting due to other reasons) has address 2001:470:CCCC:1:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 (radvd autoconfig, but I could set the Xs to ::1 if static is the way to go). Part of a routed /48.
- Windows station has IP 2001:470:CCCC:1:YYYY:YYYY:YYYY:YYYY/64 (autoconfig, and I would like to keep it this way if possible) on interface "Wi-Fi"

  - I intend to set IP 2001:470:CCCC:2::1/64 on interface "vEthernet (WSL)" and to enable autoconfig for all systems on it. Also part of the /48 so replies will reach my Raspberry Pi.

The main issue I have noticed while trying to go with this configuration is that my Raspberry Pi doesn't receive any routes so that it knows how to forward 2001:470:CCCC:2::/64 packets to my laptop. How should I go with this?

Is it even possible to do this with automatic configuration, or does my laptop need to at least receive a predictable, fixed IP address?

I have not tried with a fixed address yet, in hopes that I could make this work automatically.

Do note this is a home network. I have configured no firewalls although the Windows laptop might give me pain with its own firewall. If I feel like I need more security I can use existing posts to help me configure a firewall on the Pi, so please don't comment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main issue I have noticed while trying to go with this configuration is that my Raspberry Pi doesn't receive any routes so that it knows how to forward 2001:470:CCCC:2::/64 packets to my laptop. How should I go with this?

Add a static route to the Raspberry Pi. This should work fine:

```
ip route add 2001:470:CCCC:2::/64 via 2001:470:CCCC:1:YYYY:YYYY:YYYY:YYYY
```

The host's address is already fixed (it doesn't need to be predictable in order to be static). As long as your LAN keeps using the same /64, the Windows system should always select the same interface identifier.

- "True" dynamic configuration would require Windows to perform DHCPv6 Prefix Delegation in order to obtain a /64 from your Raspberry Pi. (Your DHCPv6-PD server would automatically add the correct route for every PD lease it issues.)

  But although Windows seems to have *some* APIs for programs to request an IA_PD, I could not find any mentions of WSL actually making use of this feature, so this remains just a theory.
- If I had to hack together a dynamic alternative, I would probably make the Windows host send out either RIPng or ICMPv6 RA packets advertising this subnet, and configure the Raspberry Pi to add kernel routes from received advertisements (e.g. using BIRD or FRR).

  RIP (including its IPv6 variant) is somewhat similar to the Prefix Information option in ICMPv6 Router Advertisements in that it's a very minimal protocol – the Windows host wouldn't actually need a full im­ple­men­ta­tion, it would be enough to just have a Python script that broad­casts a static RIPng an­nounce­ment packet every 30 seconds. It also has a small advantage over ICMPv6 RA due to only needing UDP and not raw IP sockets.

Comment: I have tried with ICMPv6 RA packets, however that leads to loss of connectivity for both the laptop and the phone (both would ignore the Pi's RA messages). I'm not sure if Windows can do RIPng. I have no DHCPv6, and DHCPv4 comes from somewhere else.

Comment: So you say that my laptop's public IP address (except for the Temporary addresses) will never change and thus I can just go ahead and add a static route?

Comment: Windows doesn't need to do RIPng on its own, I recall having a 100-line Python script to do the job. Yes, I expect that the laptop's public IP address (well, the one _not_ labelled "Temporary") will remain static.

Comment: I see, well I already had another tutorial so I will try it. If it works, I will accept this answer and put a reference to that side of the tutorial in a comment here.

Comment: If I will change the /64 in the future, will the low bits change? Not that I expect this to happen but for safety.

Comment: Yes, different prefixes _intentionally_ result in different interface IDs. But I believe there's a `netsh` option to switch Windows to the traditional way of using just the MAC address as interface ID – which will never change. (Edit: `netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled`)

Comment: I see, will search for that procedure again, do it and attach the results here.

Comment: By using https://superuser.com/questions/884215/using-windows-as-ipv6-router-for-the-network together with your advice that manually adding a static route is fine, I managed to gain IPv6 connectivity on WSL. If by tomorrow nothing breaks I will accept your answer.

Comment: OK it broke. Windows seems to not respond to Ping requests to its permanent IP address after a while (as in, probably not even responding to... I think it's called NDP?) and the Pi is unable to forward packets towards my laptop. So can you detail more on the RIP configuration? I definitely don't want to reconnect Wi-Fi after a while. radvd has all times set to "infinity".

Comment: What does `netsh interface ipv6 show addr Ethernet` report about the address? I have a suspicion "infinity" is exactly the problem...

Comment: Right now it's working again, and it's actually indeed showing "infinite" for valid and preferred lifetimes.

Comment: With no extra configuration from the Raspberry Pi side I managed to get it _reasonably_ reliably. But I need to fiddle quite a bit with my laptop. Also, I manually add the route (where do I add it automatically?) with the permanent IP, delete extra routes that prevent the laptop from responding to ICMPv6 packets and just work with it

Comment: Dropping this, I'm changing ISPs (not out of my own volition, mind you). The new ISP is promised to get IPv6 connectivity itself, and I might be able to just use prefix delegation. I have a friend already on that ISP and he ran a VMware virtual machine and that VM got an IP address directly (I was able to SSH into it); perhaps WSL will also do that (really Hyper-V on behalf of WSL). Will let you know if this configuration is still necessary.